# Comparing projects online

Tags: spring-boot, beyondcompare

In my remote machine they have blocked to download any exe or zip files, in my earlier projects I was using beyond compare to compare my projects. But now I could not install beyond compare in my remote machine since it needs zip or exe files needs to be downloaded. So anyone has any recommendation to compare projects online(spring boot maven project), it would really save me.

Comment: Can you downlaod the install exe, rename it, upload it and then download it on the remote machine? Then rename it back to exe and try to install it. If it works, then you solved your problem and found a hole in the security system of "them"

Answer (score 0):

If your remote machine allows downloads of .msi files, an MSI installer for Beyond Compare is available on the [Alternate Installers for Windows](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_dl4_winalternate) page.

If software installs on the remote machine are restricted, you can create a portable install of Beyond Compare on your local machine, then copy the portable install folder to the remote machine. To create a portable install, run the .exe installer, then select **Create Portable Install** as the install type. Portable installs are completely self contained, so they don't require admin rights. Because they're self contained, portable installs don't add Start Menu entries and they don't support the right click comparison menu in Windows Explorer.